# Which HTTP request method should be used for a like button

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

A like button is something we see on YouTube or Facebook, there is a counter associated with it.

I wonder how we should go about implement such a button. Specifically how should we communicate with the backend when a user clicks on this button? Should the button use GET or POST to talk to the backend? It makes sense to me for using POST since we are incrementing the number of likes on the backend but some tutorial I found said we should use GET since POST is typically used in the context of a form to POST the form data to the backend.

I know this is quite an open ended question but I been googling the answer for a while and haven't found a convincing one.

Comment: I'd probably go with a PUT

Comment: Agreed, PUT would be better

Comment: `GET`: retrieve resource (readonly), `POST`: create new resource, `PUT`: update existing resource, `PATCH`: make partial update on a resource.

Comment: `GET` is free to be crawled by search engines and such, you certainly wouldn't want to increment your counts just through that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say it depends on your backend framework convention of it. If you build your own backend from scratch, you may want to follow an existing convention from other projects.

Taking ruby on rails as an example for my answer, its convention is to map HTTP verbs and urls to certain actions for "resourceful routes", which is described on https://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions.

RFC2616 also describes the difference between `PUT` and `POST`:

> The fundamental difference between the POST and PUT requests is
>   reflected in the different meaning of the Request-URI. The URI in a
>   POST request identifies the resource that will handle the enclosed
>   entity. That resource might be a data-accepting process, a gateway to
>   some other protocol, or a separate entity that accepts annotations. In
>   contrast, the URI in a PUT request identifies the entity enclosed with
>   the request -- the user agent knows what URI is intended and the
>   server MUST NOT attempt to apply the request to some other resource.
>   If the server desires that the request be applied to a different URI

As the comments on your question suggest, I'd also go with `PUT`.